# Scale all components to a certain size in swing

Tags: java, swing, layout, resize, jtextfield

Is it somehow possible to scale all JTextFields to a certain size without making a custom class?

I don´t want to replace all elements in my form

Answer (score 1):

When you create the text fields you should use the constructor that specifies the number of characters you want to be displayed at one time. For example:

```
JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);
```

then a minimum of 10 characters will be displayed at one time.

Comment: The problem is, I´ve created my UI with Intellij´s Gui Designer. I don´t have any constructor calls at all

Comment: @Nachbar90, That is why I don't use a IDE to create my GUI windows for me. I spend my time learning how to use the API, not the IDE. If you ever switch IDE's your code won't work in the new IDE. So the solution is simple, don't use the IDE except for compiling and debugging.